# Animation working on iPhone but NOT working on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, animation

I have an app developed for both iPhone and iPad.
All features work on both devices, both on emulator and on a real devices. All but one.
I'm using storyboards and I triple checked if I connected everything in both iPad and iPhone Views with the same class I am using.

That one feature that isn't working is animation of an `UIImageView`.

So, I have this image that I want to move to another location, called on - `viewDidAppear`.

here is the code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
_fessor.frame = (CGRectMake(_sweden.frame.origin.x+20, _sweden.frame.origin.y-10,  
_fessor.frame.size.width, _fessor.frame.size.height));
[UIView commitAnimations];

// _fessor is ImageView im animating;

// _sweden is the button representing the country I want my _fessor to go to
```

So, this code works perfectly on iPhone (both emulator and a real device).
So why shouldn't it work on iPad (again, both emulator and device)

Also, if anyoneneeds some more data, just tell me which exactly data you need. Cos I don't see what else could cause the problem

EDIT: `The animation DOES work, when I click on a button and call the animation method. But it DOESN'T work when I call it on - viewDidAppear`

Comment: `beginAnimations:` and `commitAnimations:` have been discouraged since iOS4 in favour of the block based animation methods of UIView. Have you tried doing it that way?

Comment: Nope. I haven't...I will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this block for animations:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0. options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    _fessor.frame = (CGRectMake(_sweden.frame.origin.x+20, _sweden.frame.origin.y-10,
                                _fessor.frame.size.width, _fessor.frame.size.height));
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // when your animation finished
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

First check all the value you are passing is related with ipad size

May be issue is: you are passing frame size is perfect for iphone but not perfect  for iPad.

May be useful:

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenBound.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenBound.size.height;
```